# How can say that a function input should be a list?

Tags: list, function, haskell, constraints

I need to prototype a function, saying toList, which takes a list as its only argument, and returns a list of lists (whose type is the same that the original list).
For example [Char] will give us a [[Char]].

I've tried :

```
(List a) => a -> [a]
```

which can't work as the Class List does not exist.

How should I do then ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Throw away your notion of classes, and things in Haskell will be easier!

Comment: Oh : it's becaused i am used to the Java conception of classes. It's nearly my first functionnal programming (I've done a little of scheme, before, but not for serious projects).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
f :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

Tails is a good example of this:

```
tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

Usage:

```
 tails [1,2,3] == [[1,2,3], [2,3], [3],[]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much : that worked :) So i just have to add a couple of braces for both input and output.